# Erro The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: codeigniter

Olá, atualmente sou iniciante em codeiginiter e preciso entregar um CRUD de projeto na faculdade, até o momento fiz conexão com o banco, listei tudo.
Mas quando clico em adicionar novo ocorre o erro, acredito que seja erro de configurações.. Então quando clico no Cadastrar Novo, que está no add.php, ocorre o erro, nem sei mais oq fazer...
Segue:

ERRO ESTA AQUI:
http://prntscr.com/kz21eg

config.php
http://prntscr.com/kys0jm

controllers/Estado.php

load->model('estado_m', 'm');
    }

    function index(){
        // "estados" é referência ao armazenamento de tudo que vier de "estado"
        $data['estados'] = $this->m->getEstado();
        $this->load->view('layout/header');
        $this->load->view('estado/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('layout/footer');
    }


    // Agora vou criar a Função adicionar novo registro
    public function add(){
        $this->load->view('layout/header');
        $this->load->view('estado/add');
        $this->load->view('layout/footer');
    }

}


models/Estado_m.php

`db->get('estado');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->result();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}`


views/estado/add.php


    `Adicionar Estado
    " class="btn btn-success">Página Principal`


views/estado/index.php

        " class="btn btn-success">Cadastrar Novo

        
            
                
                    Código
                    Nome
                    Sigla
                    Criado
                    Opções

```
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $estado->idestado; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $estado->nome; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $estado->sigla; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $estado->criado; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Alterar</a>
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php 
                    }
                }    
            ?>

        </tbody>

    </table>
</code>
```

Comment: Qual erro está apresentando?

Comment: Nossa cara, esqueci do principal... Erro está aqui: http://prntscr.com/kz21eg (sempre que clico em adicionar novo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema, era erro com `mod_rewrite`.

Agradeço à atenção!